# JDialog disposing another window

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm currently working on a java game which opens up with a "start screen" frame. In the startscreen, I have a button called buttonLogin. Once you press buttonLogin, a login dialog launched by a LoginDialog class will pop up asking you for a username and password. In the dialog there are two buttons, login and cancel. Once you press login, my game will open, but the start screen is still visible.

My problem is that I do not know how to write code in the actionPerformed method of my LoginDialog class to close the existing StartScreen window.

Keep in mind that I am writing in the LoginDialog class and not the StartScreen class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can use the `setVisible` method or the `dispose` method.

If needed, you can just pass your `StartScreen` instance as a parameter to your `LoginDialog` class.

Another approach would be to give your `LoginDialog` class a setter for an 'after-login' action. The `StartScreen` can then create and set an action which disposes the startscreen.

*Edit*

To make the 'after-login' action a bit more clear, I meant something along the lines of

```
public class LoginDialog{
  Action afterLoginAction;
  public void setAfterLoginAction( Action action ){
    afterLoginAction = action;
  }
  public void loginButtonPressed(){
    //do your stuff
    if ( afterLoginAction != null ){
      afterLoginAction.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( ... ) );
    }
  }
}

public class StartScreen extends JWindow{
  public void showLoginScreen(){
    LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
    loginDialog.setAfterLoginAction( new Action(){
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
           StartScreen.this.dispose();
       }
     } );
    loginDialog.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the after-login method of my StartScreen class, do I write this.dispose(); and then called it in the LoginDialog class?

Comment: @Anonymous181 I clarified my answer (but in the mean time you already accepted it so I suppose it was not so unclear after all)

Answer (score 0):

use `dispose();` method of JDialog class